# jQuery Ajax success variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the next function. My PHP script returns an array with element `error` with value 'ERR':

```
var updatePaymentType = function(plan_pt_id, pt_id){
    var error = null;
    var data = new Object()
    data["function"]             = "update";
    data["payment_type_id"]      = pt_id;
    data["plan_payment_type_id"] = plan_pt_id;
    data["data"]            = $("#saveform").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?=ROOT_PATH?>/commission/plan/edit/id/<?=$this->editId?>",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success : function (data)
        {
            error = data['error'];
            alert(error); // All works. Output ERR
        }
    });
    alert(error); // Not work. Output null
    return error;
};
```

My function should returns an error. But it returns `null`.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AJAX requests are asynchronous, meaning the value isn't set until *after* you already returned (the `success` handler runs *later*, when the server responds with data).

To *return* the error type you have to make it synchronous with `async: false` like this:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    ...
```

But this locks up the browser, it's better to call whatever uses the value from your `success` callback, like this:

```
    success : function (data)
    {
        var error = data['error'];
        functionThatTakesError(error);
    }
```

Comment: This looks like the problem. To further explain, the "a" in ajax stands for asynchronous, meaning that your code will not wait for the http request to return before continuing execution. In this case, your return statement will be executed long before the ajax request has returned a value, making it impossible for your outer function to return the value from the server. By using a callback, you can avoid this and pass the value to the proper method as soon as it is returned from the server :-)

Comment: Thanks. It works pretty. I am using your second variant with handleErrors function.

Comment: How would you access that variable error in another function if needed?