# Accessing a variable from outside of returned ajax success is breaking my code

Tags: jquery, ajax

Okay so basically what I am trying to do is get the created id value of "slot_id" which is returned from a MySQL insert. (works), then I am trying to set the new tr's id with the returned value of the slot_id. The variable slot_id is being set I guess I am just using this wrong. Here is the code. if i add a console.log(slot_id); in the success it returns the value.

```
$('#add_slot').click(function(e){
        var slot_id;
        date = $("#slot_date").val(); 
        start_time = $("#slot_start").val(); 
        end_time = $("#slot_end").val();
        speaker_id = $("#speaker").val();
        speaker = $("#speaker option:selected").text();
        event_id = $("#event_id").val();
        last_row = $("tr:last").hasClass('odd');
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax/process_slot.php',
                    data: {
                        date: date,
                        start_time: start_time,
                        end_time: end_time,
                        speaker_id: speaker_id,
                        event_id: event_id
                    },
                    success: function(response){
                            var $bodyresp=$(response);                 
                        var resp = $bodyresp.filter("#response").text();
                        slot_id = $bodyresp.filer("#slotid").text(); 
/// slot_id is the problem child. Why is it when I access it below to set the tr id value to slot_' + slot_id ......
                        $("#flash_message").html(resp);
                        $('#mask , .popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
                            $('#mask').remove();  
                        });                    
                    }
                    });
        if(last_row === false){                             
        $("#slot_table").find('tbody')
        .append($('<tr id="slot_'+ slot_id +'" class="odd">')
            .append($('<td>' + date + '</td>' + '<td>' + start_time + '</td>' + '<td>' + end_time + '</td><td>'+ speaker+'</td><td><a class="delete_row" href="#delete_row">Delete Row</a></td>')
            )
        );

        }else {
        $("#slot_table").find('tbody')
        .append($('<tr id="slot_'+slot_id+'" class="even">')
            .append($('<td>' + date + '</td>' + '<td>' + start_time + '</td>' + '<td>' + end_time + '</td><td>'+ speaker+'</td><td><a class="delete_row" href="#delete_row">Delete Row</a></td>')
            )
        );
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    })
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax success variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958676/jquery-ajax-success-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a couple of things here. The slot_id is out of the scope... well, it's declared without a var, so it's a global (and so will be available, but hoisted), but hasn't actually been populated yet. Your next step of code is running before the ajax request has returned. Try putting the following block in a deferred, like

`$.ajax(...).then( stuff with slot_id )`

That means the code won't run until the ajax function has returned.

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/